# Can a 3rd party Azure AD B2B manage their own permissions for my protected API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a protected API, where 3rd parties B2B users and daemon services can access.

Can the 3rd party somehow manage permissions to my API by forwarding claims during authentication?

I don’t want to provide a management interface of permissions for users, if they can manage it in their own Azure tenant.

Answer (score 0):

I afraid the answer is no.

As the users access your application as B2B users, I suppose your application is single tenant application. If so, the guest users will access your application in your tenant directly. Your application won't exist in guest users' tenants.

Even if your application is multi-tenant application and your application exists under external users' tenant, they will also unable to manage the permissions themselves.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible through [Application Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles).

Comment: How can the external tenant user manage the permissions of your application?